# Android setItemOnClickListener not working for DrawerList

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I found this tutorial on how to create a navigation drawer list for my android app - http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/add-navigation-drawer-android 
Which I thought was great and was going really well, I now have a navigation panel which pulls out when the burger icon is clicked, with my menu options on it. 
However, I can't get the click listener for the menu items to work. Below is the section of the code which isn't working:

```
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private String mActivityTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DatabaseController databasecontroller =  new DatabaseController(this);
    Challenge currentChallenge = databasecontroller.getChallenge("challenge01");
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.challengeText);
    text.setText(currentChallenge.getName());
    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

    addDrawerItems();
    setupDrawer();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

private void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] pagesArray = { "Home", "Inspire Me", "Timeline" };
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pagesArray);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I have run the debugger on it and discovered that at the line

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
```

I get the error:

```
No such instance field: 'mAdapter'
No such instance field: 'mDrawerList'
```

But they must have been defined before that to make the list?

I've done some digging and seen other people having similar errors, the answers suggested included restarting android studio and removing ProGuard from gradle - both of which I've done but had no success. Any thoughts?
(I'm pretty new to android/can't remember much Java, so answers for dummies would be much appreciated!)

Comment: Does it crash ever? Or is it just the clicks not working? I'm not sure what those error messages refer to, as you've certainly got those fields. If the only thing not working is the drawer clicks, that's usually because the layout is incorrect. The drawer must be listed last within the `DrawerLayout`. If there's anything after it, it will be under another `View` which can interfere with touch events.

Comment: You are amazing! That was it!! Thank you so much.